# Notice: undefined offset with str_word_count

Tags: php

I'm having an issue with the function **str_word_count()** with my PHP.

I have this piece of code:

```
$array_cadena = str_word_count($row[0]);
echo "<td>";
for ($i = 0; $i < $half_words; $i++) {
    echo $array_cadena[$i] . " ";
};
```

It works without problems, but if I leave the code like that I'll experience problems with the accents, punctuation marks and numbers. So I decided to add the following...

```
$array_cadena = str_word_count($row[0], 1,'1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,á,é,í,ó,ú,ñ,.,;');
```

But in the browser, I see this error:
Notice: Undefined offset:

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't see the `str_word_count()`  **function**  ...  Am I missing something?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php

Comment: We don't know anything about `$half_words` and `$row`, My guess it that you just access an key in `$array_cadena` that doesn't exist.

Comment: charlist is added like `'1234567890áéíóúñ.;'`, not `'1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,á,é,í,ó,ú,ñ,.,;'`

Comment: @Zak http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-word-count.php and the comment below yours; it's a core php method/function.

Comment: Presumably, `$half_words` contains a number that is larger that the `$array_cadena` length

Answer (score 0):

Use the char list without comman as follows:

```
$array_cadena = str_word_count($row[0], 1,'1234567890áéíóúñ.,;');
```

Comment: I did it, but nothing changed... :(